# Ayuda para arreglar este codigo

Tags: android-studio

Estoy realizando un proyecto que por medio de un "FloatingActionButton" abre un cuadro de dialogo, en el hay un EditText que solicitan una informacion. Al aceptar, se supone que debe crear un CardView dentro de un RecyclerView con la informacion ingresada en el EditText y adicional guardar la info en un archivo .txt en el almacenamiento interno del dispositivo.

Hago todo el proceso que me enseñaron pero me arroja un error exactamente en esta linea `if (!NoMatricula.getText().toString().equals("")) {` que en el logcat muestra como si no estuviera bien instanseado el EditText.

Por favor, una ayuda con esto, les agradeceria mucho si son especificos con la respuesta. Como les digo, soy nuevo en esto.

**Activity extends de DialogFragment**

```
public class RegistroParqueo extends DialogFragment {

    private RecyclerView registroRecyclerView;
    private RegistroAdapter adapter;
    private ControlAlmacenamiento control = new ControlAlmacenamiento(getActivity());

    private EditText NoMatricula;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        registroRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_Registro);

        try {
            adapter = new RegistroAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(control.leerRegistro()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No existe un archivo aún", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adapter = new RegistroAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        registroRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        registroRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registroRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());



        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogo_registroparqueo, null);

        NoMatricula = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtxNoMatricula);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if (!NoMatricula.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            try {
                                control.agregarRegistro(NoMatricula.getText().toString());
                                adapter.setRegistro(Arrays.asList(control.leerRegistro()));
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Registro agregado con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al agregar el registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recuerda que debes escribir algo primero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();

    }

}
```

**XML del diálogo**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Registrar Parqueo"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtxNoMatricula"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="No. de Matricula"/>


    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**Clase que controla el almacenamiento**

```
public class ControlAlmacenamiento {

    private Activity activity;
    private String registro = "";
    public static final String FILE_NAME = "registro.txt";

    public ControlAlmacenamiento(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void agregarRegistro(String registro)throws IOException{
        registro = registro.concat("".equals(registro)?"":";");
        registro = registro.concat(registro);
        guardar();
    }

    public String[] leerRegistro()throws IOException{
        cargar();

        return registro.split(";");
    }

    public String leerRegistro(int posicion)throws IOException{
        cargar();
        String[] listaRegistro = registro.split(";");
        return listaRegistro[posicion];
    }

    private void guardar() throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream reg = activity.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        reg.write(registro.getBytes());
        reg.close();
    }

    private void cargar() throws IOException{
        FileInputStream rec = activity.openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        int r;
        registro = "";
        while ((r = rec.read())!=-1)registro += String.valueOf((char)r);
        rec.close();
    }

    public void eliminar(){
        activity.deleteFile(FILE_NAME);
        registro = "";
    }

}
```

**Error en el LogCat**

> 2020-01-25 14:34:38.576 2918-2918/com.example.parkingcontrol
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.parkingcontrol, PID: 2918
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream
>   android.app.Activity.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null
>   object reference
>           at com.example.parkingcontrol.ControlAlmacenamiento.guardar(ControlAlmacenamiento.java:38)
>           at com.example.parkingcontrol.ControlAlmacenamiento.agregarRegistro(ControlAlmacenamiento.java:22)
>           at com.example.parkingcontrol.dialogo.RegistroParqueo$2.onClick(RegistroParqueo.java:83)
>           at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: El problema no lo tienes en el `if`. Lo tienes en la función `guardar` de la clase `ControlAlmacenamiento`. Si miras bien el error del logcat, te está diciendo que estás ejecutando `openFileOutput` sobre un objeto `null`. Y el objeto es la variable `activity`. Revisa que en el constructor de la clase `ControlAlmacenamiento` estás recibiendo bien la `activity`.

Answer (score 0):

El error de debe a que el contexto especificado no tiene valor, y se tiene dentro del método :

```
  private void guardar() throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream reg = activity.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        reg.write(registro.getBytes());
        reg.close();
    }
```

debes realizar un cambio enviando el contexto y usarlo para llamar el método `openFileOutput()`, primeramente cambia tu método `agregarRegistro()` para que reciba el contexto :

```
public void agregarRegistro(Context ctx, String registro)throws IOException{
    registro = registro.concat("".equals(registro)?"":";");
    registro = registro.concat(registro);
    guardar(ctx);
}
```

llama este método de esta forma :

```
control.agregarRegistro(getApplicationContext(), NoMatricula.getText().toString());
```

y modifica tu método `guardar()` para que lo use:

```
  private void guardar(Context ctx) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream reg = ctx.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        reg.write(registro.getBytes());
        reg.close();
    }
```